# How to ignore errors when generating report using JMeter -g

Tags: jmeter

how can I ignore errors and proceed to generate the dashboard report.

I have been seeing annoying errors example:

> org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples:Mismatch between expected number of columns:16 and columns in CSV file:1

Due to extra space or newline in the files, I am dealing with 8GB of huge, all these minor issues in the csv file are consuming a lot of time when generating reports.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your .jtl result file is malformed. Default JMeter configuration should produce something like:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1519031460845,364,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,1598,115,1,1,364,0,227
```

If you amended your JMeter configuration for any reason try reverting it to default and if the issue still persists - inspect your .jtl result file and identify the problematic sampler result entries to detect what causes these extra spaces or line breaks.

If you run JMeter tests on one JMeter instance and generating dashboard using another JMeter instance - they must have the same configuration in terms of `jmeter.save.saveservice` properties, otherwise dashboard generation might fail or results will be inconsistent.

References:

- [Results file configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: Thanks for the advise Dmitri, however I think the issue is mainly due the end of scheduler, where by the threads start to stop but some thread didnt close properly and the data isn't completely written. So I have thread groups running one after another. This may sound like a minor issue, but when dealing with huge dataset, these incomplete data is no joke.