# JMeter report folder not being created: "Mismatch between expected number of columns"

Tags: jmeter

I'm facing this weird issue when trying to run some JMeter tests on 3 remote servers. When my test run ends, sometimes it does not arrives to generate the expected report (50% of the times).

When I look at the jmeter.log file, I have the error in the title.

I also found the question "[how-to-ignore-errors-when-generating-report-using-jmeter-g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859352/how-to-ignore-errors-when-generating-report-using-jmeter-g)", but it didn't help very much.

I'm trying to analyze the csv files from both a success and a failure, but I can't find any significant differences between them.

Can someone please help me with this one? It's driving me crazy for about a week now...

It seems that I can't attach any files, but I could easily attach the csv files or my jmeter.properties file if it helps...

I would like to thank you in advance for the help,

**EDIT:**
I'm using the same JMeter version on my 3 VMs (4.0 r1823414), and the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties seems all the same to me.

Before your answer, I did some other tests, I have some interesting results:
When I launch my JMeter's test, I use the command:

```
./jmeter -n -t $testName.csv -e -o $testName -R 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.96,192.168.1.175 -Ghps.target=$1 -Gtest.duration=$2 -Gtarget.path=/ -Gservers.nb=3 -Gusers.max=1000 -Gtarget.protocol=https -Gtarget.url=target.url
```

Witch sometimes succeeds and sometimes produces only the CSV file, bugging on the reports generation (the reason I post this question)

If after I ran this test, I do:

```
./jmeter -l $testName.csv -e -o $testName
```

The report is created with no errors, using the same CSV file previously generated...

Best regards,
Marc

Comment: First, make sure all 3 remote machines are having the same Jmeter version and java version. Second, share the error log, it will others to response faster to your problem.

Comment: Hi Ubik, sorry for the delay to post a reply. Actually I didn't had the time to test it yet. I'm doing a lot of work and my workaround of splitting in 2 steps (test first and report after) works well. As soon as I can test your answer (invert the -t and -o options) I will post another comment.
Thank you again, Marc

Answer (score 0):

Check you're using last JMeter version which is 4.0 currently, 2 bugs related to your issue were fixed in it.

Second option is that the file was not fully written so last row might be incomplete leading to this error.

Third and last option is that your configuration for report differs between the 3 machines.

Check properties 
- sample_variables
- jmeter.save.saveservice.* (all properties starting with jmeter.save.saveservice)

In your command line, you seem to have inverted -t and -o options. Could it be the reason ?

Comment: I have some more information, I just edited the original question :)

Comment: I updated my answer, if issue persists please share whole jmeter.log file.